# HTML caching with loadbalancing

Tags: server, iis-6, f5

I have a caching issue. My server setup is something like having 2 web servers hosted on IIS 6.
Both are in the F5 load balancing which will be controlled by network team.
When I make some changes to html file I get the old versions from Public URL (www.xyz.com).
But when I request individual servers with the ip addresses they are good.
Funny part is that when I renamed the code paths on the individual servers, IP address request fails but not the public address. It still pulls from caching somewhere.
I disabled output caching and kernel caching on both IIS settings.
My Hunch is F5 caching somewhere. Is there anything that I can do before reaching networking folks?

Answer (score 0):

The F5 doesn't cache at all unless configured to do so, I would reach out and talk to them. As a guy who once worked primarily on a network team, thank you for taking the time to debug and diagnose your own stuff first, they are lucky to have you!